# Assigning Individual Colors to a Gradient Color Scheme in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to find the best way to display this stacked area chart in ggplot2 in R. My issue is the amount of variables I'm trying to display while also keeping the chart readable. I've currently got 17 different variables that I need to keep present in the chart but have a few in particular I'd like to single out. My code as it stands is this:

```
full <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Year, y=value) +
geom_area(aes(fill=variable)) +
theme(legend.position='right') +
theme(legend.title=element_blank())
```

I thought I could add something like this to achieve an effect of giving the entire graph a gradient theme but then singling out a couple variables with a separate fill color entirely.

```
full + scale_fill_grey() + 
scale_fill_manual(values=c('Xval1'='red', 'Xval2'='blue'))
```

If anyone knows how to actually do this I'd be extremely grateful. Alternately, if you can think of a better way entirely to display this data I would be open to hearing suggestions.

Comment: You will get more assistance if you provide a minimally reproducible data set for df.

Comment: Sorry for not including this, still pretty new to the community and how everything works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you do not give an example of your data, it is impossible to give you detailed advice. But I can show you in an example how you can achieve your goal (if I correctly understood your goal...).

I first create som data and the plot as in your post:

```
df <- data.frame(Year=as.factor(rep(2000:2005,each=9)),
                 value=runif(6*9,0,10),
                 variable=as.factor(rep(1:9,times=6)))
full <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Year, y=value)) +
                  geom_area(aes(fill=variable,group=variable)) +
                  theme(legend.title=element_blank())
```

There is no need for `theme(legend.position='right')` since this is the default. Note that I added the aesthetics `group` to `geom_area`. If it is missing, `ggplot` does not know which values belong to the same curve and produces an empty plot.

Now I create a scale manually in two steps. First, I create a scale of grays with 9 levels, because I have nine levels in `df$variable`. And then I modify a few of these levels:

```
my_scale <- gray.colors(n=9,start=0.2,end=0.8)
my_scale[c(4,7,8)] <- c("red", rgb(0,0.8,0.6), "#ff7f00")
full + scale_fill_manual(values=my_scale)
```

As you can see, it is possible to use named colours, hexcodes, or `rgb` (which actually returns a hexcode).

Instead of picking to colours yourself, you could also make use of colourbrewer, which overs excellent palettes. Similarly to `gray.colors` above, one can use the command `brewer.pal` to create a palette:

```
pal <- brewer.pal(9,"Set1")
my_scale <- gray.colors(n=9,start=0.2,end=0.8)
my_scale[c(4,7,8)] <- pal[1:3]
full + scale_fill_manual(values=my_scale)
```

[image]

The arguments to `brewer.pal` are the number of colours you want and the name of the palette. You can browse the various palettes on http://colorbrewer2.org/.

Comment: My apologies for not including a reproducible dataset (still new to both ggplot and stackoverflow in general). I should've thought to just create a palette externally as a vector then reassign specific elements of it. Thank you for the help!